# The specified user or domain group was not found on SharePoint Server 2010

Tags: error, service-application

We have a SharePoint 2010 server.

While clicking Manage Service Application link in Central Administration it thorws error

"The specified user or domain group was not found."

Below is server log for the generated Correlation ID :

> 11/21/2011 16:01:33.67 w3wp.exe (0x30D8) 0x3AF0 SharePoint Foundation
>   Logging Correlation Data xmnv Medium Name=Request
>   (GET:http://01hw361477:2550/_admin/ServiceApplications.aspx)
>   12f59625-51ad-4888-be18-96d23743b4e8
>
> 11/21/2011 16:01:33.67 w3wp.exe (0x30D8) 0x3AF0 SharePoint Foundation
>   Logging Correlation Data xmnv Medium Site=/
>   12f59625-51ad-4888-be18-96d23743b4e8
>
> 11/21/2011 16:01:33.71 w3wp.exe (0x30D8) 0x3AF0 SharePoint Foundation
>   Topology 887s High The profileStoreLanguagePacksApplied field in the
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication class
>   has been deleted. The old value will be preserved in the
>   UpgradedPersistedFields collection under the
>   profileStoreLanguagePacksApplied key. Consider writing upgrade code to
>   copy this value to a new location.
>   12f59625-51ad-4888-be18-96d23743b4e8
>
> 11/21/2011 16:01:33.71 w3wp.exe (0x30D8) 0x3AF0 SharePoint Foundation
>   Topology 887s High The nextSynchronizationStage field in the
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication class
>   has been deleted. The old value will be preserved in the
>   UpgradedPersistedFields collection under the nextSynchronizationStage
>   key. Consider writing upgrade code to copy this value to a new
>   location. 12f59625-51ad-4888-be18-96d23743b4e8
>
> 11/21/2011 16:01:33.71 w3wp.exe (0x30D8) 0x3AF0 SharePoint Foundation
>   Topology 887s High The synchronizationRunRetryCount field in the
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication class
>   has been deleted. The old value will be preserved in the
>   UpgradedPersistedFields collection under the
>   synchronizationRunRetryCount key. Consider writing upgrade code to
>   copy this value to a new location.
>   12f59625-51ad-4888-be18-96d23743b4e8
>
> 11/21/2011 16:01:33.71 w3wp.exe (0x30D8) 0x3AF0 SharePoint Foundation
>   Topology 887s High The currentBDCMA field in the
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication class
>   has been deleted. The old value will be preserved in the
>   UpgradedPersistedFields collection under the currentBDCMA key.
>   Consider writing upgrade code to copy this value to a new location.
>   12f59625-51ad-4888-be18-96d23743b4e8 11/21/2011 16:01:33.71 w3wp.exe
>   (0x30D8) 0x3AF0 SharePoint Foundation Topology 887s High The
>   m_listBDCMAs field in the
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication class
>   has been deleted. The old value will be preserved in the
>   UpgradedPersistedFields collection under the m_listBDCMAs key.
>   Consider writing upgrade code to copy this value to a new location.
>   12f59625-51ad-4888-be18-96d23743b4e8
>
> 11/21/2011 16:01:33.71 w3wp.exe (0x30D8) 0x3AF0 SharePoint Foundation
>   Topology 887s High The syncFullImport field in the
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication class
>   has been deleted. The old value will be preserved in the
>   UpgradedPersistedFields collection under the syncFullImport key.
>   Consider writing upgrade code to copy this value to a new location.
>   12f59625-51ad-4888-be18-96d23743b4e8
>
> 11/21/2011 16:01:33.71 w3wp.exe (0x30D8) 0x3AF0 SharePoint Foundation
>   Topology 887s High The currentSynchronizationRunStatus field in the
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication class
>   has been deleted. The old value will be preserved in the
>   UpgradedPersistedFields collection under the
>   currentSynchronizationRunStatus key. Consider writing upgrade code to
>   copy this value to a new location.
>   12f59625-51ad-4888-be18-96d23743b4e8
>
> 11/21/2011 16:01:33.71 w3wp.exe (0x30D8) 0x3AF0 SharePoint Foundation
>   Topology 887s High The synchronizationRunStartDateTime field in the
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication class
>   has been deleted. The old value will be preserved in the
>   UpgradedPersistedFields collection under the
>   synchronizationRunStartDateTime key. Consider writing upgrade code to
>   copy this value to a new location.
>   12f59625-51ad-4888-be18-96d23743b4e8
>
> 11/21/2011 16:01:33.71 w3wp.exe (0x30D8) 0x3AF0 SharePoint Foundation
>   Topology 75dz High The SPPersistedObject with Name NewProfileService,
>   Id becf4cc8-2dce-4e88-8640-b8fa6928407b, Parent
>   d9763291-4dd8-44e7-bef1-53f4376d681a failed to initialize with the
>   following error: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The specified user
>   or domain group was not found. --->
>   System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException: Some or all
>   identity references could not be translated. at
>   System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection
>   sourceAccounts, Type targetType, Boolean forceSuccess) at
>   System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(Type targetType) at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimProviderManager.GetProviderUserKey(String
>   encodedSuffix) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims....
>   12f59625-51ad-4888-be18-96d23743b4e8 11/21/2011 16:01:33.71* w3wp.exe
>   (0x30D8) 0x3AF0 SharePoint Foundation Topology 75dz High
>   ...SPClaimProviderManager.GetProviderUserKey(String encodedSuffix) at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.GetFullUserKeyFromFullName(String
>   fullName) at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAce1.GetBinaryId(UTF8Encoding
>   encoding) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAce1..ctor(String
>   principalName, String displayName, Byte[] securityIdentifier) at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAcl1.Add(String principalName,
>   String displayName, Byte[] securityIdentifier, T grantRightsMask, T
>   denyRightsMask) at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAcl1..ctor(String persistedAcl)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIisWebServiceApplication.InitializeAcl()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObject.Initialize(ISPPersistedStoreProvider
>   persisted... 12f59625-51ad-4888-be18-96d23743b4e8
>
> 11/21/2011 16:01:33.71* w3wp.exe (0x30D8) 0x3AF0 SharePoint Foundation
>   Topology 75dz High ...StoreProvider, Guid id, Guid parentId, String
>   name, SPObjectStatus status, Int64 version, XmlDocument state)
>   12f59625-51ad-4888-be18-96d23743b4e8
>
> 11/21/2011 16:01:33.71 w3wp.exe (0x30D8) 0x3AF0 SharePoint Foundation
>   Runtime tkau Unexpected
>   System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException: Some or all
>   identity references could not be translated. at
>   System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection
>   sourceAccounts, Type targetType, Boolean forceSuccess) at
>   System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(Type targetType) at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimProviderManager.GetProviderUserKey(String
>   encodedSuffix) 12f59625-51ad-4888-be18-96d23743b4e8
>
> 11/21/2011 16:01:33.71 w3wp.exe (0x30D8) 0x3AF0 SharePoint Foundation
>   Monitoring b4ly Medium Leaving Monitored Scope (Request
>   (GET:http://01hw361477:2550/_admin/ServiceApplications.aspx)).
>   Execution Time=40.5573353778179 12f59625-51ad-4888-be18-96d23743b4e8

Recently we have changed the domain of the server and have not checked it from then(if related).

What could be the possible cause for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By only looking at log you provided I would say your (User profile) service account is no longer valid. This could be the issue if you changed the server domain.

Take a look at this explanation:

[SharePoint 2010, “The specified user or domain group was not found”](http://architectevangelist.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/sharepoint-2010-the-specified-user-or-domain-group-was-not-found/#comment-7)

> SharePoint 2010 stores security information using the Subject
>   Alternative Name as a literal strings as a result renaming or removing
>   associated accounts will cause the service to fail.

Also following links could provide some additional info:

- [Changing Service Accounts in SharePoint 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2010/01/08/changing-sharepoint-2010-service-accounts.aspx)
- [How to change the Farm Service Account in SharePoint 2010](http://www.tsls.co.uk/index.php/2011/01/21/how-to-change-the-farm-service-account-in-sharepoint-2010/)
- [Moving Sharepoint 2010 server from one AD to another?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12345/moving-sharepoint-2010-server-from-one-ad-to-another)

**Edited** One more similar question:

- [Move SharePoint to new Domain](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26769/move-sharepoint-to-new-domain)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Struggled a lot and got an exact solution for this:

[http://techilatalk.com/remove-spmanagedaccount-not-working](https://web.archive.org/web/20140313041905/http://techilatalk.com/remove-spmanagedaccount-not-working)/

This solution gives database based approach to handle this issue.

Comment: This link seems to be broken.

Comment: @SlavenSemper I've fixed the link. :)