# Move SP 2013 from one company to another company

Tags: move

My company has took over a new company recently. Now I need to move their complete SP 2013 installation to our existing SP 2013 Farm. New Company SP sites are hosted externally and internally. There is no AD trust relation ship between both the companies. Please suggest me the best options to move the farm and how can I deal the service accounts from new company?

Comment: you need the two FARMS to be connected ? or you want to move the SharePoint CONTENT of that company into your sites ?

Comment: No need to connect 2 farms. Just need to move everything (from new company) to my existing setup.

Answer (score 1):

Their are two Possibilities.

**Move the Content Only**
In this case, you have to move the content from new company farm to your existing farm.In this approach you just need to move the content Database.To get this done you have to think about this.

- Make sure the new farm is on the same Patch level as your existing farm(for smooth migration)
- Create the New Web Application(s) in your existing farm as per the new company farm. Make sure same authentication, Same Solutions should deploy before hand,
- Create New DNS record( old may be not possible totally different domain).
- Deploy all customization(if any) and web.config changes
- [Backup the content Database from new company sql server
- Restore it to exisitng server SQL serve][1](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287899.aspx)r
- Mount the database to web application.
- [Run the Migrate user command to migrate all users from old to new](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607729.aspx).
- Test it.( i would first try few content database for testing).

**2nd Method is take full farm backup.**
In this method, you can setup a brand new farm in your existing domain and then restore the Full farm backup using new company's farm backup. But in this scenario you have the two farms in your domain.
[Move SharePoint to new Domain](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26769/move-sharepoint-to-new-domain)

Comment: Thanks Waqas for the response. I will be going with option 1 as I don't need 2 farms in my environment. Also there is a clarification from my side, that the new company which we acquired is using SP 2010. In this case the option 1 is still valid?

Comment: yes, it will migration/upgrade for them. when you mount the content database it will upgrade the content, for few cases you may need to run the upgrade-content database command to complete the process. i would also recommend to go through tech-net migration documents.