# Map Previous domain and new domain user so they can access same MySite?

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am working on shaerepoint 2010. I have user with  previousdoman/username, now we changed with newdomain/username. Username is same, for ex.
previously: abc/xyz, new user: qwe/xyz. I am working with sharepoint defauly **MySites**. http://domain/personal/username/default.aspx.

When we are login with previous account it is working fine and i can see all my document library. but when I logged in with new account it is giving me an error "Your personal site cannot be created because a site already exists with your username."

I can't change central admin setting which will be possible solution for this error.

https://sharepointdojo.wordpress.com/2013/06/04/resetting-user-profiles-what-a-conflict/

beacuse it will create new site I want existing site. any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on [Move-SPUser](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/move-spuser?view=sharepoint-ps), that PowerShell command can help you.

However, if you try to migrate from a DomainA to a DomainB, you have to follow some steps already explained [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12345/moving-sharepoint-2010-server-from-one-ad-to-another).